# Is there anyway to install credo globally?

Tags: elixir, linter

I'm a newbie with elixir, and I'm trying to configure my text editor (vim + ale as lint engine) with the credo linter for elixir, but seems like there is no way to have it installed on the system. Its documentation just say how to install it on your project as a dependency. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the [readme](https://github.com/rrrene/credo#using-credo-as-stand-alone):

**Using Credo as stand alone**

If you do not want or are not allowed to include Credo in the current project you can also install it as an archive:

```
git clone git@github.com:rrrene/credo.git
cd credo
mix deps.get
mix archive.build
mix archive.install
```

Important: You have to install bunt as well:

```
git clone https://github.com/rrrene/bunt
cd bunt
mix archive.build
mix archive.install
```

You will now be able to invoke credo as usual through Mix with mix credo. This option is especially handy so credo can be used by external editors.

Comment: Oh!, I didn't see that. I was just checking the installation section.

Answer (score 6):

In 2021, just install it with:

```sh
$ mix escript.install hex credo
```

Then run it with:

```sh
$ credo
```